# imagejpeg() and PHP vs JPEG extension

Tags: php, facebook, watermark

On my app, users choose a picture to upload on their Facebook wall. I auto add a watermark using [example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php). The page where this happens is called test3.php.
When I try this to add it to the users' wall:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$photo = "test3.php";
$message = 'Test message';

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                        'source' => '@'.$photo,
                                        'message' => $message
                                       )
                                     );
```

I get: `Uncaught FacebookApiException: Invalid parameter`, probably because test3.php doesn't have a image extension.

Is their any way I can fix this? I've tried using `test3.php?testing.png` to trick the upload-script, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Im sure source should be a full url

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tried this script with the image test.png. It works fine.

Comment: Use htaccess and replace your url from test3.php?image=photo.jpg to test3/photo.jpg. Then use replaced url for facebook upload

Comment: @RajivRisi How would this work exactly? I'm always messing those ReWrite-rules up... And what should I put in the script uploading-script? `$photo="test3/photo.jpg"`?

Comment: @RajivRisi I put this in my htaccess: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   /somepath/test3.php?image=photo.jpg   /somepath/test3/photo.jpg`, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Are you getting image output from /somepath/test3/photo.jpg

Comment: Yes, but the script doesn't accept "test3.php?image=photo.jpg"

Comment: The problem is not the file extension. 'source' => '@test3.php' means that it will take the file test3.php and upload that.

Comment: I changed "source" to "url", that worked! Even thought I don't think the url parameter is documented by Facebook.